# Google Maps on iOS error: is depending on legacy on-demand authorization, which is not supported for new apps

Tags: google-maps, codenameone

I am working on native google maps with CN1 java app. It works OK on Android, and CN1 simulator, but fails on real iPhone. The following is part of system log.

```
    Nov 12 23:57:56 My-iPhone6spou locationd[64] : getClientEffectiveRegistrationResult, /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/C483CD2D-48BB-4EB3-8AD6-440FE1C4C651/MyMaps.app/MyMaps, com.company.cn1.maps, , CLClientRegistrationResult, kCLClientRegistrationResultFailedUnavailable, CLCommonLocationServicesEnabled, 1
    Nov 12 23:57:56 My-iPhone6spou locationd[64] : message 'kCLConnectionMessageLocation' received from client 'com.company.cn1.maps'
    Nov 12 23:57:56 My-iPhone6spou locationd[64] : Client com.company.cn1.maps (0x10283ae00) is unsubscribing to notification kCLConnectionMessageLocation
    Nov 12 23:57:56 My-iPhone6spou locationd[64] : Client com.company.cn1.maps (0x10283ae00) is unsubscribing to notification kCLConnectionMessageLocationUnavailable
    Nov 12 23:57:56 My-iPhone6spou locationd[64] : client 'com.company.cn1.maps' unsubscribing from location
    Nov 12 23:57:56 My-iPhone6spou locationd[64] : ClxClient, unsubscribe, 
    Nov 12 23:57:56 My-iPhone6spou locationd[64] : message 'kCLConnectionMessagePausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically' received from client 'com.company.cn1.maps'
    Nov 12 23:57:56 My-iPhone6spou locationd[64] : message 'kCLConnectionMessageLocation' received from client 'com.company.cn1.maps'
    Nov 12 23:57:56 My-iPhone6spou locationd[64] : ERROR: com.company.cn1.maps is depending on legacy on-demand authorization, which is not supported for new apps
    Nov 12 23:57:56 My-iPhone6spou locationd[64] : Client com.company.cn1.maps (0x10283ae00) is subscribing to notification kCLConnectionMessageLocation
    Nov 12 23:57:56 My-iPhone6spou locationd[64] : ERROR: com.company.cn1.maps is depending on legacy on-demand authorization, which is not supported for new apps
    Nov 12 23:57:56 My-iPhone6spou locationd[64] : Client com.company.cn1.maps (0x10283ae00) is subscribing to notification kCLConnectionMessageLocationUnavailable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you include the build hint `ios.locationUsageDescription` as described [here](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html)?

It's mentioned in the location API JavaDocs too.